# Merge uneven tables using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, merge, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an issue where i have to combine multiple dim table to arrive at a single table.

I have a table (tbl1) like this -

```
Country----Year----Srcname---Value
  A--------2011------FAI-----100
  B--------2010------FAI-----200
  C--------2009------CSS-----300
  D--------2008------BAT-----110
```

Another table (tbl2) like this

```
Country----Year----Srcname---Progname---Value
 A--------2011------UES--------EMP-------100
 A--------2011------UES--------FMD-------150
 B--------2010------UES--------MAP-------200
 C--------2009------UES--------FMD-------300
 C--------2009------UES--------QSP-------400
 C--------2009------UES--------EMP-------300
 D--------2008------UES--------TASC------110
```

I have to combine tbl1 and tbl2 into a single table like below tbl3

```
Country----Year----anyname---Value
  A--------2011------FAI-------100
  B--------2010------FAI-------200
  C--------2009------CSS-------300
  D--------2008------BAT-------110
  A--------2011------EMP-------100
  A--------2011------FMD-------150
  B--------2010------MAP-------200
  C--------2009------FMD-------300
  C--------2009------QSP-------400
  C--------2009------EMP-------300
  D--------2008------TASC------110
```

How to do this?

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that in the result table you show any rows from tbl2 show the Progname column under anyname where results from table 1 should show SrcName?

Comment: @JustinM - The result table should show all the records of tbl2 and tbl1. The program name should come under the source name in the result table. The resulting column could be any name. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Country, Year, Srcname as combinedCol, Value FROM tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT Country, Year, Progname as combinedCol, Value FROM tbl2
```

Comment: Thanks @TTeeple, i am getting an error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword union.

Comment: @user2962438 then your code is different than what is in this answer.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Big fan of your blogs. Made my day seeing you respond here :D

Comment: are you using order by clause in your query ?

Comment: @user2962438 add the code you've tried to the question. Should be quite easy for us to tell you what you've done wrong.

Comment: @Muhammed Ali, Thanks a ton!! Orderby was the issue.

Comment: Not a problem if you do want to use order by Just put all the unions inside a CTE or Drived table and ORDER BY the retunred results from there but unfortunately you cannot use ORDER BY in a query where you are using union/union all operator. :)

Comment: @MuhammedAli You can as long as the ORDER BY is at the end of the UNION ALL.  A neat trick is to use the ordinal position of the columns as well, i.e.:

    `SELECT 'a', 'b'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a', 'c' 
    ORDER BY 1`

This will sort the results by the first column.  If you want to sort by the second column descending, you would do the following:

    `SELECT 'a', 'b'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a', 'c' 
    ORDER BY 2 DESC`

You can see the difference by taking out the DESC and seeing that the 'b' row will come first with no DESC, and 'c' comes first with DESC.

Comment: @TTeeple cheers pal its a good trick and much cleaner, The way I was suggesting is because recently I have been doing a lot of UNION queries and I was ordering by the column which was used in the actual UNION Query so I had select the Column so I could ORDER BY by results by that column and then used and Outer query to leave out the column in the final returned result set :) anyway thanks for the  tip :)